# perl insert and or replace string variable into a string

Tags: regex, perl

the requirement I have is to check a string and based on particular set of chars either insert or replace with prefix string

```
$prefix = "DV1";
```

Following are my source $input strings:

```
SS7.ABCWT2.RSND.LTE1.QR
IT4.ABCET2.VCE2.QR
Y88.ABCNT2.MIM.EDR2.QR
9C5.ABCS.MIM.EDR2.QR
```

the first chars before first . can be of any length
but after the first . the chars ABC remain constant followed by any one character - these four chars will always be there in my input string.
after these 4 chars, the i/p string may have two alphanumeric chars - T2 in this case.

what needs to be done is check if $input has "T2" (can be any two alphanum chars) and if it has then replace those 2 chars with D1 (any two chars from $prefix)

if $input does not have "T2", then insert $prefix

Comment: I do not understand the specification. Can you add more input data plus expected output or clarify the algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done quite straightforwardly with a single substitution. This program demonstrates

The pattern looks for the sequence `.ABC` followed by any non-dot character. The `\K` protects that part of the pattern from being changed. Then there may be two optional non-dot characters, followed by a dot. The replacement string is `D1` if the two optional characters were present, or the value of `$prefix` if not

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $prefix = 'DV1';

while (<DATA>) {
  s/\.ABC[^.]\K([^.]{2})?(?=\.)/$1 ? 'D1' : $prefix/e;
  print;
}

__DATA__
SS7.ABCWT2.RSND.LTE1.QR
IT4.ABCET2.VCE2.QR
Y88.ABCNT2.MIM.EDR2.QR
9C5.ABCS.MIM.EDR2.QR
```

**output**

```
SS7.ABCWD1.RSND.LTE1.QR
IT4.ABCED1.VCE2.QR
Y88.ABCND1.MIM.EDR2.QR
9C5.ABCSDV1.MIM.EDR2.QR
```

Comment: @Borodin.. Wanted to confirm, wouldn't your `while` load the complete file in the memory?? Or does it rather happen in case of `foreach`??

Comment: Thanks to gurus ... I was stuck in this for couple of hrs. :)

Comment: A `while (<>) { ... }` loop like this reads only a single line of data at a time. If you write `for (<>) { ... }` then Perl will read the *entire* file into memory and then loop over the lines it has stored

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code you can try..

I am assuming that, `T2` can be a string of length 2 any alphanumeric characters.. It can be **A4, or 5B**...

```
#!/perl/bin
use v5.14;
use warnings;

my $str = "9C5.ABCS.MIM.EDR2.QR";
my $str1 = "SS7.ABCWT2.RSND.LTE1.QR";

my $prefix = "DV1";

my $file = 'D:\Programming\Perl\Learning Perl\chapter_1\demo.txt';


open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;

foreach (<$fh>) {

    if (m/(^.*\.ABC\w)\w{2}\./g) {
        s/(^.*\.ABC\w)\w{2}\./$1D1\./;
    } else {
        s/(^.*\.ABC\w)\./$1$prefix\./;
    }
    say;  # Takes current line as default($_). We don't need to specify it.
}
```

**Input File**: -

```
SS7.ABCWT2.RSND.LTE1.QR
IT4.ABCEX4.VCE2.QR
Y88.ABCN5W.MIM.EDR2.QR
9C5.ABCS.MIM.EDR2.QR
```

**Output: -**

```
SS7.ABCWD1.RSND.LTE1.QR  # Replace T2
IT4.ABCED1.VCE2.QR       # Replace X4
Y88.ABCND1.MIM.EDR2.QR   # Replace 5W    
9C5.ABCSDV1.MIM.EDR2.QR  # Does not contains T2. Add DV1
```

Comment: The `\w` pattern matches upper and lower case letters, digits, and the underscore, so it is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. There is no point in including the digits a second time with `[\w\d]`.

Comment: @Borodin.. I didn't knew that.. So shall I replace it with just [\w]??

Comment: @Borodin You are right.. I cross-checked.. It works.. I edited the code accordingly.. :)

Comment: @Borodin.. Actually I am still learning Perl.. So, I keep on forgetting things.. Will need lots of practice.. Thanks :)

Comment: @Borodin.. If the code is ok now.. Can you please remove the downvote, if its yours??

Comment: @Borodin.. Now I think it's ok.. Replaced it with : - `\w{2}` .. Do you suggest any more correction??

Comment: @Borodin.. OK.. Is there anything else, I can improve in code?

Comment: Well you you should *always* `use strict` and `use warnings`; you could use single quotes on your file name string so you don't have to double up the backslashes; you don't need double quotes around `$!` and you don't need to specify `$_` explicitly with the matches or substitutions. But it's a fair program

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code, and tell me if it fits your needs :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -l

use strict;
use warnings;

my $text =<<EOF;
SS7.ABCWT2.RSND.LTE1.QR
IT4.ABCET2.VCE2.QR
Y88.ABCNT2.MIM.EDR2.QR
9C5.ABCS.MIM.EDR2.QR
EOF

my $prefix = "DV1";

for (split "\n", $text) {
    s/^(\w+\.ABC\w)T2/$1D1/ || s/^/$prefix/;
    print;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
SS7.ABCWD1.RSND.LTE1.QR
IT4.ABCED1.VCE2.QR
Y88.ABCND1.MIM.EDR2.QR
DV19C5.ABCS.MIM.EDR2.QR
```

Comment: This code doesn't appear to do the *if $input does not have "T2", then insert $prefix* part of the specification

Comment: It's more constructive to tell me what I misunderstood than downvote

Comment: @sputnick.. Not my downvote but you reversed the specification..  `if $input does not have "T2", then insert $prefix` -> You have inserted `D1` and if it contains `T2` you have replaced with `$prefix`. But that doesn't deserve a down vote I think..